# Extending formulas to a large number of rows in a column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel sheet with one of the columns having around 25000 entries.

Now, I create a new sheet – say `Sheet2` – and I have a simple formula like this in the first column of `Sheet2`.

I went to the first row and entered

```
=Sheet1!C2
```

Now I dragged this down to the entire 25000 rows to copy the entire column from the first sheet here through this formula. Is there a better way to do it?

I tried double clicking on the <kbd>+</kbd> sign at the bottom right of the cell but that did not seem to work for me.

Comment: Sometimes a task is more suited to a DBMS + SQL, is this one of them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you're trying to copy a formula 25,000 rows down. You can use the Name box to do this quickly.

Assuming `Sheet2!A1` has the formula `=Sheet1!C2`

1. With **Sheet2** active, type `A25000` into the Name Box and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will select cell `A25000`.

   [image]
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Up ↑</kbd>.  This selects cells A1 to A25000.
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>. This extends the formula in A1 down to A25000.